# Как изменить Look and Feel (Swing)

Tags: java, swing

Я пишу GUI приложение на Java Swing. Мне нужно изменить Look and Feel на не стандартный, то есть на FlatLaf. Как мне это сделать? Может я что-то не правильно подключаю?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Changing L&F
    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf());
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Home().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил спустя 5 минут.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf());
```

Заменить на

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatLightLaf");
```